# Can I copy a list of items to another list?

Tags: list, workflow

I would like to copy a list of items to another list when an item is add to yet a 3rd list
Here is my example
I have a list of tasks

id  task
1   brush teeth
2   drink coffee
3   drive to work

My next list is AssignTo list
id AssignTo
1  Jane Doe

When Jane Doe is entered I have a work flow create new records in a new list call WorkAssigned

Task          AssignedTo
brush teeth   Jane Doe
drink coffee  Jane Doe
drive to work Jane Doe

Every time a a person is added to the AssignTo list a workflow is trigger to task assign to the person entered to the workassinged list.

My problem is since there is no looping in the workflow I "Hardcode" adding the 3 task.  If the user added aother task I have to add it to the workflow.

I am looking for something more automatic (I wanted to loop and add all times in the task list)

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? There is looping in SP 2013 workflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do looping in SharePoint 2010 workflows in code but not in SharePoint Designer. To handle this step I would create a custom workflow activity to handle adding the tasks. Then include that custom activity in the SP designer workflow.

Here is a [walk-through for creating a custom activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231574.aspx)